# How to construct a time vector in years with an existing data set (python)?

Tags: python

I am trying to construct a time vector in years with an existing dataset.

I have tried

```
df = pd.read_csv("temp.csv")
date = df['DATE'].apply(lambda x : str(x)[:4])
time_vector = np.arange(date.min(), date.max() + 1)
```

This code gives me the error: `can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`. To address this error, I've tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv("temp.csv")
date = df['DATE'].apply(lambda x : str(x)[:4])
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])  # Ensure 'DATE' column is in datetime format
time_vector = np.arange(df['DATE'].min().year, df['DATE'].max().year + 1)
```

But this second code only prints out `[1970]`.

Does anybody have suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: It helps us reproduce your problem if you provided your example dataset as _text_ instead of a screenshot. You can use a code block to format it. I've done it for you now, but please this keep in mind for future questions

Answer (score 2):

I've constructed a mock dataframe resembling yours:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "DATE": [19950103, 19960406, 20230330],
    "OTHER_COLUMN": [1, 2, 3],
})
print(df)
```

Dataframe:

```
       DATE  OTHER_COLUMN
0  19950103             1
1  19960406             2
2  20230330             3
```

Your first attempt was very close - the one thing you had left to do is to convert your year values to int. The error was about adding 1 to a string year, which Python can not do. Here's how it can be done:

```
dates = df.DATE.astype(str).str[:4].astype(int)
np.arange(dates.min(), dates.max() + 1)
```

Output:

```
array([1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005,
       2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016,
       2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023])
```

---

You second approach failed because `pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])` treated int values as timestamp, instead of string-type representation of date.
You could try converting it to string this time:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.DATE.astype(str)).dt.year
```

```
0    1995
1    1996
2    2023
```